# recoverPublicKey() returns undefined

Tags: signature, cryptography

```
function hashData(){
    const data = {
      sendAmount: sendAmount,
      recipient: recipient,
      sender: address
    }
    return keccak256(utf8ToBytes(JSON.stringify(data)));
  }

  function signData(){
    return secp256k1.sign(hashData(), privateKey);
  }

  function recoverKey(signature){
    signature.recoverPublicKey(hashData());
  }
```

I am trying to sign a hashed message with a private key and return the public key with it.
When I use `recoverKey`, it returns undefined.
I am using ethereum-cryptography 2.1.2 and documentation from here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@noble/curves#ecdsa-signature-scheme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `recoverKey` function is missing the `return` statement. It should be:

```js
function recoverKey(signature){
  return signature.recoverPublicKey(hashData());
}
```